# Export data to csv using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, d3.js

so i want to use d3.js library and use a chart.
i want to display how many projects has been opened in one year,
and to show each month the sum of projects that have opened.

i saw this code:

```
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/connectedscatter.csv",
...*GOING ON MORE*...
```

but i dont want to read data from csv, i want to read it from my DB and send it to the View.
myabe in a ViewBag..

im attaching the source code:
https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/connectedscatter_basic.html

i would love to know if theres a way that i could send to d3 the data in a different way
and not from csv, thanks !

Comment: do you want to get data from controller as CSV using EF

Comment: You would normally send the data as JSON.  See eg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-aspnet-core-ef-step-01?view=vs-2019

Comment: You could get data from database by using EF Core and return data to View by using `d3.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `d3.json(url,function(data){})` to return data from the controller to the view.

Here is a simple demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class TestModels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

@section Scripts{
    @*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script>
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
            width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        //Read the data
        d3.json("Home/Test", 
             // Now I can use this dataset:
            function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                // Add X axis --> it is a date format
                var x = d3.scaleTime()
                    .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date) }))
                    .range([0, width]);
                console.log(x);

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
                // Add Y axis
                var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([8000, 9200])
                    .range([height, 0]);
                svg.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
                // Add the line
                svg.append("path")
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr("fill", "none")
                    .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                    .attr("d", d3.line()
                        .x(function (d) { return x(d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date)) })
                        .y(function (d) { return y(d.value) })
                    )
                // Add the points
                svg
                    .append("g")
                    .selectAll("dot")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date)) })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.value) })
                    .attr("r", 5)
                    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")         
});
    </script>
}
```

3.Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;
    public HomeController(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var data = new JsonResult(_context.TestModels.ToList());
        return data;
    }
}
```

4.Result:
[image]